# Nested scopes clarification

Tags: ruby, scope

I've read somewhere that blocks in Ruby have nested scopes, what does that mean? I've read about nested scopes and some claim those are scopes that create new scopes. I'm not sure if this is true with Ruby because blocks are between `do/end` and if you define some variable there, for example, it's not creating a new scope. Can someone please clarify this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby's blocks are lexically scoped and thus, *close over* their outer scope(s).

For example:

```
foo = 'foo'

->{

  # new scope can see outer foo
  puts foo # => 'foo'

  # new scope can manipulate outer foo
  foo = foo + '!'

  bar = 'bar'

}.call

puts foo # => 'foo!'

# outer scope cannot see variables created in block scope
defined?(bar).nil? # => true
```

Comment: So basically 'nested scopes' mean that blocks can manipulate objects within their surrounding scopes?

Comment: That's the gist of it, yes. You should research lexical scoping and closures, though.